Is this expression wrong about single/split supply op-amps?
I'm trying to understand why some op-amps are sold as "single-supply" even though it seems all op-amps can be used with single supply voltages.
And I came across this paper which states:

Figure 1b shows an application where the input signal is referenced to ground. In this case, input signals of less than 2V will not be accurately handled by the op amp. A “single-supply op amp” would handle this particular application more successfully.

Is there a mistake here? Because if not, I completely misunderstood the point. Shouldn't it say: A “split-supply op-amp” would handle this particular application more successfully?

The paper is old enough that most op-amps could not operate within approximately 2V of the power supply rails. The exception is op-amps "designed" for single supply operation.

A “single-supply op amp” would handle this particular application more successfully

The phrase “single-supply op amp” (notice the hyphen) means an op-amp that designed for single supply operation. These are especially designed to operate very close the the negative rail which is zero volts.
The regular split-supply op-amp would not be able to operate well in a single supply configuration.
Many modern op-amps are called rail-to-rail. These can operate in some cases less than 50mV to the both rails. Rail-to-rail operation is not always available on both input and output. These amplifiers can easily operate both split rail and single supply.
As always, read the datasheet to be certain.

The statement is correct.
Here is the figure from your app note:

You had best treat “single-supply” as an adjective referring to the particular model of op-amp.
By convention, a “single-supply op-amp” is one designed to have an input common mode voltage range that typically includes the negative supply pin and an output that can swing very close to that voltage as well.
As well, note  that op-amps virtually never have a ground pin, rather they have two supply pins. The schematic is thus unambiguous. There are two supply pins, one of which goes to a substantial positive voltage, the other to ground.
In the situation shown, a single-supply op-amp will function better for input voltages approaching the negative supply (in this case, ground) than one that is designed for split supplies. We also have "rail-to-rail input/output" op-amps. And op-amps with rail-to-rail outputs but not inputs and possibly the reverse. In the case of Fig 1b, a voltage follower is shown, which requires both inputs and output to be able to work over the range of Vin.
Of course if you imagine a different situation than is shown in Fig 1b, with the negative supply connected to (say) -5V rather than ground, then that op-amp will probably function better (even if it is a 'single-supply op-amp') since the output of a single-supply op-amp cannot get quite to the negative supply rail (especially if it is sinking current).. well, barring some trickery such as internal supplies generated from the single supply†.
† There is at least one monolithic op-amp design which has an internal charge pump to allow the input range to cover the full supply range without the ugliness of conventional rail-to-rail inputs.

There's a difference between using an opamp with a single supply, and a single supply opamp.
In the first case you're using a standard opamp with a single supply by using a bias voltage or artificial ground, such as a voltage divider to give a Vcc/2 reference.
In the second case, you have an opamp designed to have a common mode range that extends to the negative rail.

The language is a bit ambiguous. If you were to provide a split supply, the circuit would work better. On the other hand, if you only have a single supply, you'd be better off with an opamp intended for use with a single supply.

With less than 2V input the opamp will not work well with single supply. so isnt the paper wrong? it says the opposite.
